# Picking a particular model from regsubsets

Tags: multiple-regression, model-selection

I ran regsubsets in r from the 'leaps' library. I have gotten some 16 models in their order of which is best according to certain criterion.

How do I select, say, model no.14 from this order and run it individually?

[image: regsubsets - summary output]

Answer (score 0):

we usually select models by a *criterion*, AIC , BIC, Cp or R^2. Unfortunately, I don't see any of these, so I cannot tell you which model to choose.

The stars only tell you which variable is dropped at which step.

Comment: The stars actually tell you which variables are included in the model.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a programming question, but it does have one statistical aspect.

The object returned by `regsubsets` doesn't include the fitted models -- the point of `regsubsets` is that finding the best models only needs the residual sum of squares for the model, not the rest of the fit. As the help page says

> The model search does not actually fit each model, so the returned object does not contain coefficients or standard errors. Coefficients and the variance-covariance matrix for one or model models can be obtained with the coef and vcov methods.

You can compute the coefficents of the 14th model with `coef(the_object,14)` and the variance-covariance matrix with `vcov(the_object, 14)`